# Quick Question Regarding Conversion of Units

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using the following code to display kg vs lbs in for my data in a table.

For some reason it is not working correctly and is giving me huge numbers.  Any ideas?

I am using DDUnitConverter [(https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter](https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter))

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *repsText = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"reps"] description];

    NSNumber *weightInPounds = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"weight"]floatValue]];
    NSNumber *weightInKilos = [[DDUnitConverter massUnitConverter] convertNumber:weightInPounds fromUnit:DDMassUnitUSPounds toUnit:DDMassUnitKilograms];

    NSString *weightText = nil;
    NSString *cellText = nil;
    BOOL isKgs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"wantsKGs"];
    if (isKgs == 1)
    {
        weightText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", weightInKilos];
        cellText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Set %i: %@ reps at %@ kgs",indexPath.row + 1, repsText, weightText];
    }
    else
    {
        weightText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", weightInPounds];
        cellText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Set %i: %@ reps at %@ lbs",indexPath.row + 1, repsText, weightText];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
}
```

Comment: Glad you're liking the unit converter! Just remember that, despite being open source and free and all that fun stuff, there is a license that goes with it. :)

Comment: Thanks Dave.  As long as I reference your project on my site, thats ok right?

Comment: @Faisal nope; read the "readme" file. The copyright & license need to be included in the actual software.

Comment: Ok cool just checked it out.  So just include it in the code where I am using it?

Comment: @Faisal that won't work either, because comments are stripped out by the compiler and thus it wouldn't be "included in all copies" of the app.  Generally people include it on an about screen, or a "legal" screen off an about screen or something.

Comment: Ok, perfect.  Ill do that then. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveDeLong could you change it to a standard license (Creative Commons sounds like what you want)? I honestly would love to use this library in an app I'm developing, and have no problem giving you credit to my users, but I can't clearly understand what's written and that makes me hesitant to use it. On the contrary, a standard license would be fully tested legally and commonly accepted

Comment: @JoeCortopassi the license is essentially "use however you like, but include the copyright stuff somewhere visible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this is an easy problem to solve. `weightInKilos` and `weightInPounds` are `NSNumber` instances. When you use the `%i` formatter in formats, it means you are supplying an integer. The integer you end up supplying is the pointer value to each object. Since you want the string value of each NSNumber, use the instance method `-stringValue`.

Here's an updated version of your code based on those changes.

```
- (void) configureCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell atIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    NSString *repsText = [[managedObject valueForKey: @"reps"] description];

    NSNumber *weightInPounds = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [[managedObject valueForKey: @"weight"] floatValue]];
    // Alternatively you could just use ‘[managedObject valueForKey: @"weight"]’ if the ‘weight’ attribute is a number.

    NSNumber *weightInKilos = [[DDUnitConverter massUnitConverter] convertNumber: weightInPounds
                                                                        fromUnit: DDMassUnitUSPounds
                                                                          toUnit: DDMassUnitKilograms];

    BOOL isKgs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"wantsKGs"];
    NSString *weightText = (isKgs ? [weightInKilos stringValue] : [weightInPounds stringValue]);

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Set %i: %@ reps at %@ lbs",indexPath.row + 1, repsText, weightText];
}
```

Remember that you have to follow the memory management rules when dealing with objects. When you create an object using an `-init...` method, you have to be sure to release it. In your code that means `weightText` and `cellText`.

PS: DDUnitConverter is a great find. I'll have to keep it bookmarked if I ever need it in future projects.